# Existe alguma forma de traduzir os meses no input type date?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Como eu traduzo o input do tipo date?

no `html` eu botei `lang="pt-br"` mas mesmo assim continua inglês.

A imagem é só um exemplo!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O input já está em PT uai. O seu problema é o resto do componente que está em inglês pelo visto.... Onde vc pegou esse código? Seu sistema operacional está em inglês? Sou navegador é em inglês?

Comment: *A imagem é só um exemplo! *

Comment: Amigo posta a imagem de seu componente.

Comment: Estava olhando e acho que o componente pode pegar a lingua do pc do usuario logado... No meu pc, aparece em PT-BR no pc do meu parceiro de trabalho mostra em ingles, será que é isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente o seu componente está em inglês porque seu browser ou sistema operacional está usando inglês como língua nativa, é interessante verificar isso.